# bluetooth disabled on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, atheros

I already installed ubuntu 16.04 and everything works fine except my bluetooth. I have old notebook Asus k53TK with atheros bluetooth and wifi card and wifi is working fine. WHen i was on ubuntu 14.04 bluetooth worked so it's a little weird that now i just can't enable it.

When i try to reset hciconfig with command:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
```

it prints: Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)

Logs:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    5.342543] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    5.342579] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.342586] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.342591] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.342601] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.044581] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.044587] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.044594] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b23b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04ca:3002 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 13)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

sudo hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:21 acl:0 sco:0 commands:7 errors:0
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my issue with 04ca:3002 Lite-On Bluetooth
[here is description](https://bugzilla.altlinux.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29081) and the patch, and this is the [patch itself](https://bugzilla.altlinux.org/attachment.cgi?id=5859)

I am not very experienced in Linux, but it seems that the following comment helped me to resolve in particular.

```
Comment #3 From freuser 2013-06-17 20:32:15
The order of manual patch application:
rmmod btusb
modprobe ath3k
echo "04ca 3002" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath3k/new_id
Checked on kernels   3.9.4-std-pae and 3.8.13.2-std-def
```

thanks everyone, who made some efforts for resolving this issue
now my mouse is working :)

Comment: i am not what is the reason , but this solution is not perfect ,

Comment: it is again off , when system restarts , - anyway another repeating of below 3 strings in root mode helps again
    rmmod btusb
    modprobe ath3k
    echo "04ca 3002" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath3k/new_id